# Outer join with a subquery changes the count of rows in mysql

Tags: hiveql

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM erp.cir_order
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT increment_id
    FROM magento.sales_flat_order sfo
    JOIN Erp.cir_order co
        ON co.order_num = sfo.increment_id
    WHERE co.status LIKE '3' AND
          DATE(SFO.created_at) >= '2016-02-01' AND
          DATE(SFO.created_at) <= '2016-06-31'
) AS ch
 ON 
cir_order.order_num = sq.increment_id
    WHERE cir_order.status LIKE '3' AND
          cir_order.order_num = ch.increment_id
```

Why should the count(1) change the "total" number of records returned by the outer query with change in conditions in the inner query?

Since I am using A LEFT OUTER JOIN, I don't see why filtered out `incrementId`'s from the subquery should change the number of records returned by outer query? EVent if I am using `incrementId` in the joining condition, that's a left join by which I mean I need everything from cir_order table where status is LIKE '3'.

(I am using it as a subquery on purpose). Just not sure why it behaves like it does here.

Could I get some help on this?

EDit:

My question is how do I get the total number of records returned by outer query while not caring about the records filtered because of the condition in ON Clause. I believe we use outer join for that? That's what I tried using. I mean, when I say LEFT OUTER JOIN, ignore even when order_num did not find a match with increment_id, take that order_num in account and give me the total number of rows

EDit2: My original query looks like this:

```
SELECT count(1) as TotalCirOrders, sq.statusDifferentCount as faultCount
FROM 
Erp.cir_order corder
left JOIN 
(
SELECT count(1) over() as statusDifferentCount, sfo.created_at as createdAt, sfo.increment_id as incrementId
FROM 
Magento.sales_flat_order sfo
LEFT JOIN 
Erp.cir_order cir_order
ON
cir_order.order_num = sfo.increment_id
where
cir_order.status ='3'
AND
sfo.status NOT IN ('refund', 'partial_refund', 'exchange', 'refund_cash', 'partial_refund_cash', 'refund_points')
AND
TO_DATE(SFO.created_at) >= '2016-02-01'
AND
TO_DATE(SFO.created_at) <= '2016-06-31'
) 
AS sq
ON
corder.order_num = sq.incrementId
where
corder.status ='3'
GROUP BY statusDifferentCount;
```

Edit 3:  I need to count the number of order_num and increment_id. Though the condition is different. I get date field from sales_flat_order table only so in business terms I need to count order_num of cir that we "created" in the given range and then the other thing I need to count is "number of increment id, created in the given range, with status i.e NOT IN the mentioned list"

Comment: Because thats the nature of a left join. Also your query doesnt make sense to me. Why are you doing a left join and then you dont have a `ON` clause?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: I do , I do. I missed it while writing the query. My question is how do I get the total number of records returned by outer query while not caring about the records filtered because of the condition in ON Clause. I believe we use outer join for that? That's what I tried using. I mean, when I say LEFT OUTER JOIN, ignore even when order_num did not find a match with increment_id, take that order_num in account and give me the total number of rows

Comment: @Strawberry see his comment, he edited it.

Comment: What do you want to count? It is not clear. What is clear, is that the subquery can influence the count you do: that is expected, as the join for a particular value for `order_num` can match more than 1 record in the subquery, which means the count goes up. Again: what (in business terms) do you want to count? If you want to count orders (and only each once), then you must use `COUNT(DISTINCT order_num)`. But still then, the `GROUP BY` can make a single order be counted in different groups.

Comment: @trincot; I need to count the number of order_num and increment_id. Though the condition is different. I get date field from sales_flat_order table only so in business terms I need to count order_num of cir that we "created" in the given range and then the other thing I need to count is "number of increment id, created in the given range, with status i.e NOT IN the mentioned list".

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. I will come back with an answer. I am surprised to see the `over()` keyword in your SQL, as that is not supported by MySql. Which database engine are you on?

Comment: @trincot: I am actually using hive. It works like SQL for the most part and importantly for this case atleast. I have been running my queries in mysql as well corresponsingly

Comment: If there is no *cir_order* record with status '3' for a given *sales_flat_order* record (with *order_num = sfo.increment_id*), do you still want to count that *sales_flat_order* record in the *statusDifferentCount* count (when it is within the date range and its status is not in the mentioned list)? And vice versa: if there is no *sales_flat_order* record for a given *cir_order* record with status '3', should the order_num still be counted in the first count? Really, you should add sample data and sample result in your question.

Comment: @trincot: "if there is no sales_flat_order record for a given cir_order record with status '3', should the order_num still be counted in the first count ". Yes. It should still be counted. and "sales_flat_order record in the statusDifferentCount count (when it is within the date range and its status is not in the mentioned list)", both the conditions should suffice in this case for it to be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count can be different when the sub-query returns multiple records with the same value for `increment_id`.

There is also an issue with the `LEFT JOIN`: for a `LEFT JOIN` to work as expected (different from `INNER JOIN`) you must not put any conditions on the joined table in the `WHERE` clause, because that in practice will turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (except if you'd have an `IS NULL` condition: that has sense). In your query this happens here:

```
LEFT JOIN Erp.cir_order cir_order
       ON cir_order.order_num = sfo.increment_id
where     cir_order.status ='3'
```

You can solve the above issues by moving the `WHERE cir_order.status ='3'` condition into the `ON` clause, and counting only distinct values of `cir_order.order_num`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cir_order.order_num)
... etc.
```

The other count, i.e. the count of those *increment_id* that are subject to the extra condition on *status*, you can get by moving that condition out of the `WHERE` clause into a `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN increment_id END` construct and perform a count on that:

```
SELECT     count(DISTINCT cir_order.order_num) as TotalOrders,
           count(DISTINCT 
              CASE WHEN sfo.status NOT IN ('refund', 'partial_refund', 'exchange', 
                                           'refund_cash', 'partial_refund_cash',
                                           'refund_points') 
                   THEN increment_id 
              END) as statusDifferentCount
FROM       Magento.sales_flat_order sfo
INNER JOIN Erp.cir_order cir_order
      ON   cir_order.order_num = sfo.increment_id
     AND   cir_order.status ='3'
WHERE      to_date(sfo.created_at) BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-06-31'
```

Comment: Please check the update. I already get less number of records than I should so I believe it's not related to distinct

Comment: What then do you want to count? Maybe you should provide sample data, the outcome you get, and the outcome you desire to get.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I now see that left join thing in the correct manner but s per the updated query, the count I get for statusDifferentCount is way more than the total orders which shouldn't be the case since we only have an added query to check for the status. Could you think of something why would that be? @trincot

Comment: And you explained it really really well. Thanks a ton for doing that

Comment: If the *statusDifferentCount* should never be more than *TotalOrders*, then do you mean that every record counted in *statusDifferentCount* should also be counted in *TotalOrders*? And if so, then why do you want a `left join` and not an `inner join`, because that would make that happen.

Comment: Ah, I now see your latest comment. If `right join` is what you need, then I would suggest to swap the table names and just `left join`: it is common practice to avoid `right join` as it goes against the human reading direction :)

Comment: I swapped the tables in the join in my updated answer, like explained above. Thanks for having accepted.

Comment: Now that I see the new `join`: it should be an `inner join` because the `where` condition on *sfo* will anyway require the *sfo* to match, which is what `inner join` does. Updated my answer again.

Comment: Oh yes, That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to simply wrap the whole query with a

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your query here)`

Comment: Please check the update. I would not work me I guess?